# Measuring the tradeoff of loop unrolling

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking, loop-unrolling, google-benchmark

Using google benchmark to benchmark the following functions:

```
int sumElements(int *arr, int count)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumElementsUnrolled(int *arr, int count)
{
    int sumA = 0;
    int sumB = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 2) {
        sumA += arr[i];
        sumB += arr[i + 1];
    }
    return sumA + sumB;
}
```

Benchmark results:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                    Time             CPU   Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------------
sumElements                965 ns          963 ns       723250
sumElementsUnrolled        641 ns          641 ns      1091406
```

I tried to benchmark these functions using google benchmark, and got a noticeable benefit at -O0 and -O1. I learned in several places that this is likely due to breaking dependency chains, which, if I understand correctly, leads to fewer pipeline stalls as the CPU is executing my instructions. Looking at the [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/P5vx188bT) at -O1, this makes sense: the unrolled version uses different registers for each sum variable, and the dependency chain is broken.

Questions:

1. Is this explanation correct, or am I way off?
2. If so, how do I measure pipeline stalls here? Running `perf stat` shows a much higher rate of `stalled-cycles-backend` for the unrolled version, but I don't really know if that's related.
3. If not, then what is the cause of the speedup? What does breaking a dependency chain do at the CPU level?

The benchmarking code is very simple:

```
#define SIZE 4096

int *initArray(int size)
{
    int *arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
    return arr;
}

void doBenchmark(benchmark::State &s)
{
    int *arr = initArray(SIZE);
    for (auto _ : s) {
        int sum = sumElements(arr, SIZE);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);
    }
    free(arr);
}


BENCHMARK(doBenchmark);
```

I tried identifying the cause of the speedup using `perf stat`. But I am not sure how to interpret the results.

Comment: Getting the reversed result https://quick-bench.com/q/Z679SMuTuf3qzbNYUgH_HMD5bdA

Comment: This can be a follow up question: the reversed result is for -O3. I mention -O1 in the question

Comment: You made the manual optimization with -O1, and your manually unrolled loop broke compiler's job with -O2 and -O3.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around how loop unrolling works. I understand that we are breaking a dependency chain. But what does that mean at the CPU level? Fewer pipeline stalls, or something else? And if so, how can we measure that?

Comment: Never underestimate what your compiler can do for you.

Comment: Side note why still use "C" style coding (malloc and passing "C" style arrays?)

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's just a quick benchmark, for learning purposes. I would never use that in production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR: as 273K said, You made the manual optimization with `-O1`, and your manually unrolled loop broke compiler's job with `-O2` and `-O3`.  (Mainly because of auto-vectorization.)

---

In the actual compiler-generated asm (*not* the C++ source), one of the tradeoffs of loop unrolling is larger I-cache footprint.  You can't measure the cost of that with a microbenchmark where only the unrolled loop runs; microbenchmarks in repeat loops make complicated implementations of loops like this or `memcpy` look good.  The actual cost depends on I-cache pressure in whatever program this is part of.

Another cost is that you might have more cleanup work to do for odd `count`, if your function needs to be correct for all possible `count` values (unlike your test case).  e.g. an unroll of 16 makes the worst-case cleanup 15 elements; depending on how you do the cleanup, that could be worse for smallish problems that also only run a few iterations of the unrolled loop.

---

Yes, at `-O0` where store/reload (store-forwarding latency) bottlenecks are a huge problem, manual unrolling helps for that reason.  ([Benchmarking at `-O0` is normally pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point); the bottlenecks are different from in normal cases.  In this case I think you realize that, although you didn't use `register int` for any of your variables to let a `-O0` build still keep them in registers.)

And at `-O1`, maybe allowing two scalar adds per clock instead of 1, or at least bottlenecking on front-end throughput instead of 1 loop iteration per clock bottlenecked on loop-branch throughput.

But at `-O2` / `-O3` when auto-vectorization is enabled for clang, **manual unrolling usually makes compilers do worse when auto-vectorizing**.  e.g. they'll do stupid things like shuffle into vectors of odd/even elements to vectorize `sumA` and `sumB` separately.  They're not smart, just complex pieces of machinery.

Optimal asm for this on x86-64 involves SSE2 `paddd` (or AVX2 `vpaddd` to do 32 bytes at once.)  Unrolling *that* loop by 2 can help if the data is hot in L1d cache, but that would mean a scalar unroll of 8 or 16.  (And like I said, compilers aren't good at rolling up scalar code into SIMD, especially with multiple accumulators.  Although sometimes it works if the scalar unroll factor matches the vector width.  I'd recommend keeping your loops simple)

**Unlike GCC, clang already does unroll tiny loops by default, including when auto-vectorizing.  Sometimes with multiple accumulators.**

Clang 16 `-O2` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHKEEANQKPtj0bIIKEBubAFQNZJsnaF6CcyYaAIImAOxWT5ufV4LbPpsmAGYACKbDSA96PL6bfjETbHH54f7A0Hgq5ItybG6CVHWax4Ob/N4PSFQr47Fj/SyAkEXEwAVgseHpQPBxKhrxZHy%2BxEwBGWDF%2BLFZTw5xOJJ3Je0wBwICjkDGInno6HhW3OxEu1yWdzFRK5nwlPkh1JRAIhUMNLAsSJBYLNbK%2BMLhJ0RJrt1tdAIxWIIqNdVORZgJr3NpM%2B5ONAZpGvpjOZwpJYfJ1txyNpDP91q48ft%2BsJnMTmx5fOIAojlOtyYTHI4C1onDpvD8HC0pFQnDcuMs2yWK0wlIBPFIBE0tYWAGsQJIuAA6LgVDQANkHGni8TpkkkL30nEkTdHbc4vAUIA0w9HCzgsCQaBYSTosXIlFv9/ocWQBiMXEXGjPWAAbngqwAGp4JgADuADySSMJwQ40LQBCxCeEBRAeUShA0ACecG8BhzDEFhkFRNo1QjtwvC3jKkEMLQOEtrwWBRF4wBuGItAnhRpBYCwhjAOIDHcXgPI1P%2BmCca2mCqNUXhIbh5CCJg9aCbQeBRMQ2EeFgB4EMQeAsLhCxUAYwAKKBEHQbBXH8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOogm6Fw%2Bh8SgXY2KpUQnpACyoEkjgCJxAC0kFmLwqBiRqeBYIFEALO0YV%2BBArijH4XB0oEDDoL0JRlCALx5SkaTpdlEjlfk6VFf0cRlbYSlkbUEzVZUrUdAwXSNA1MxNXlCgdZ4LQgJUEwDSVZWpb2qwSHWDb7oJ7YcJsqgAByLhFi6SJin7AJs34zhop1wrghAkAOXBzLw5FaHME7%2BHSM4bi8P4AnSdKLi8XBmGYXCbTuHB7qQzatmtx6nueDGXjAiAoKgd4PmQFAQC%2BqMoId36/txmCASBYFQTBzbwXQSHEChaGCfh2HyXThHEaRDjyVRjAEDRdEHkxLFsbQHHyTxfECa2%2BAiY4YkSbwUkyXJXEbEpB7%2BRphFaWsra6fphl8CZZnE5ZZO8DZwiiOIjkmy5agHroASHT5VKWPoanJcFoUZJFkEArF8V6Ul8Cpd16UuAV1WecEUzFbMeSVRkYcxwUDDTdHaXtd08ep50U2R41egjenY05J5%2Bf9Tng2LYsywLbdIONuDB5rRt227ftH58cdi6nedECXUQsLmIOd2w49z0AgCM5j5PU/TyDYMQ7FR62DDD1jiDMX16ti8r09pDxWkziSEAA)) made this asm for the inner loop of the non-unrolled version.  It's 6 uops (assuming macro-fusion of the cmp/jcc, which will happen on Intel and AMD CPUs, https://agner.org/optimize/), so Alder Lake can run it at one iteration per clock cycle.  (Only doing 2 loads per clock out of the 3 it's capable of...  https://uops.info/)

```
  ... compute a loop bound and zero some regs
.LBB0_5:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movdqu  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rdi + rsi]
        paddd   xmm0, xmm2                         # one vector accumulator
        movdqu  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rdi + rsi + 16]
        paddd   xmm1, xmm2                         # second vector accumulator
        add     rsi, 32
        cmp     rax, rsi
        jne     .LBB0_5             ; } while(i < max);

# Then combine to one vector
        paddd   xmm1, xmm0
# and horizontal sum down to scalar
        pshufd  xmm0, xmm1, 238                 # xmm0 = xmm1[2,3,2,3]
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        pshufd  xmm1, xmm0, 85                  # xmm1 = xmm0[1,1,1,1]
        paddd   xmm1, xmm0
        movd    eax, xmm1
  # sum in EAX  for   benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);

        cmp     rdx, rcx
        je      .LBB0_8     ; benchmark repeat loop
```

Further unrolling, and/or using AVX [with non-indexed addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes) or aligned pointers to allow single-uop memory-source `[v]paddd`, could reduce overhead enough that we bottleneck on 2 or 3 loads + vector-adds per 4 or 5 uops, letting Haswell / Ice Lake / Zen bottleneck on L1d load throughput (SIMD vector integer add throughput is at least as high as vector load throughput in all those CPUs, and `paddd xmm0, [rdi]` is single-uop on all of them, but not `vpaddd xmm0, xmm0, [rdi + rsi]`).

See also [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca)

But to get a compiler to generate further-unrolled asm, you'd want to use intrinsics like `_mm_load_si128` (aligned load, can fold into a memory source operand for legacy-SSE `paddd`, unlike `_mm_loadu_si128` unaligned load).  Or maybe use profile-guided optimization so the compiler knows this loop is truly hot and will optimize it even more aggressively.

---

**As I guessed, the asm for the manually-unrolled version involves `shufps` instructions.**  It loads 4 vectors and uses 4x `shufps` as a 2-input shuffle to get the odd vs. even elements from pairs of vectors, feeding 4x `paddd` instructions.

Also note that your unrolled version is only equivalent for even loop counts, since you didn't write cleanup code for the odd element.  And `i < count` will read past the end of the array instead of stopping early.  In the general case, `i < (count - (unroll_factor-1))` will stop after the last "full" iteration, leaving some elements leftover instead of going too far.  Notice how that expression simplifies to `i < count` for an `unroll_factor` of `1`; that's helpful for remembering it.

---

See also: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) and Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk “[What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)”

Comment: I can see how the -O2 unrolling here addresses the loop-carried dependency chain, by using two accumulators. But isn't there another dependency here: both loads in the loop body write to `xmm2`? Or is it not as significant?

Comment: @LostCoder: Register renaming makes those loads independent.  It's a write-only access so it starts a new dependency chain.  See [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) - the first section of my answer there goes into detail about loads into the same register not having a false dependency (because `movss xmm1, mem` zero-extends into the full register so it's like `movups`, not merging with the old value.)  That question later got some edits to ask more stuff.